# Angular 5 share variable between two components

Tags: html, angular

I have a shared variable I want to declare in both component and I want the components to have shared values. I was wondering if this can be done.

A.html

```
...
<button (click)="sendInfo(a,b,c)" > </button>
...
```

B.html

```
...
<div *ngIf="showData" > {{loadData()}} </div> 
...
```

A.component.ts

```
...
showData = false;
sendInfo(a: string, b:string, c:string) {
//calling webservice
showData = true;
}
...
```

B.component.ts

```
...
showData = false;
//when button from A.html clicked
showData = true;
```

So in B.component.ts I want to set the showData to true if the button from A.html is clicked.

1. How does B.component.ts know when A.component.ts has been changed?
2. How do I set this shared variable between two component?

Comment: You can use an `EventEmitter` to notify one component when the other fires the click event. But that assumes your components are in a parent-child

Comment: the components are sibiling, app.component contains both of those compoents and htmls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to share a variable between two components use a service and observable using `ReplaySubject`:

```
export class Service {
   sharedVariable$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
   updateValue(value) {
       this.sharedVariable$.next(value);
   }
}
```

In components inject the service:

```
class Component {
   constructor(public service: Service) {}
}
```

And use in html:

```
<span>{{service.sharedVariable$ | async}}</span>
<button (click)="service.updateValue(55)">set 55</button>
```

This is much better than to share variable using component bindings and future proof.

Comment: but this create infinite loop calls. I want just to check the data once when the button is clicked.

Comment: So in B.html {{ service.sharedVariable$ }} would keep printing the same value repeatedly.

Comment: there are no infinite calls. You should never call a function in a template. This is observables pattern and it prints out the last value emitted by observable.